# Should I use past tense or present tense for facts in a story that I'm telling in past tense?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, story

I learned simple present tense is used for universal truths or facts. If I'm telling the story in past tense, and I have to say a fact, should I use simple present tense?

Example:

> They ran from the tiger. Tigers are (or were?) fast animals.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the present because general truths are formulated using that tense; in this particular context of permanently valid truth, the  use of the present tense is called STATE PRESENT.

*timeless statements or eternal truths: proverbial, scientific, mathematical statements*

- Honesty *is* the best policy.
- Water *consists* of hydrogen and oxygen.
- Two and three *makes* five.

*Statements assimilated to timeless statements*
*1 not such an extreme of temporal universality: geographical statements and others of similar nature*

- The Nile *is* the longest river in Africa.
- Tigers are fast animals.

*2 restricted time span*

- Margaret is tall.

(This answer is based on CoGEL, Quirk et al, 1985, § **4.5**)

Comment: Also, saying tigers *were* fast would hurt their feelings.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Not if they are an extinct species, and what's more, if there were not a single tiger left, the tense would be correct then!